# pxe-e61 media test failure Ubuntu Dual boot Win

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8, bootloader

So I had win 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 in dual boot and it was all working fine, but after I enabled the Intel Rapid feature on win this error "pxe-e61 media test failure check cable" started showing up and I can't boot anymore. When I go to the boot menu on the BIOS none of the boot loaders appears anymore. I ran the Boot-repair program and this was the output. http://paste.ubuntu.com/9207990/

Answer (score 0):

That message means there is no network cable connected. It also means it's trying to boot from the Network, so either -

1. The network card is listed before the hard drive in the boot order in the BIOS (Check boot order)
2. The hard drive is dead/has a bad cable. (Replace the cable and/or hard drive and try again)
3. The hard drive is disabled in the BIOS. (Enable it)